# Bending radius for NM cable through stud

Tags: electrical

From what I understand from the NEC, bending radius for an NM cable must be at least 5x the diameter of the cable bundle (“romex”).

But how do you calculate this in a real life scenario. Is the radius of the wire below too little? Enough?

[image]

Comment: Good question -- 334.24 just says "the diameter of the cable" without accounting for the fact that most modern NM cables have eccentric cross-sections....

Comment: Good question! _Eagerly awaits a very code specific answer that indicates that 99% of home NM cable installations are in violation of code._ :)

Comment: @freeman so you don’t see a problem with this bend?

Comment: I've found [this](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2015/julyaugust-2015/code-hunter-bending-2014-nec/) reference (answer to 10) that *suggests* that the Code wants to use major diameter here, by analogy to the Chapter 9, Table 1, Note 9 cable-fill-rules, but I don't like that since flat cables are *anisotropic* with regards to minimum bend radius I reckon (a flat cable bends much easier if bent about one axis than the other, test it for yourself, I tried with a piece of 18/2 NISPT-2 flat cord and could barely bend it along one axis, but of course had no trouble with the other).  PI time...?

Comment: @threephaseeel Pi time haha.

Comment: @JeffGeorge -- don't laugh too hard. :) (I'm referring to submitting a Public Input to the folks who work on the NEC)

Comment: As an FYI -- I have put in Public Input 1501-NFPA 70-2020 to clarify the Code on this front.  We'll see how it goes!

Comment: IMO the radius for the bending of that kind of flat cable (12/2) should be based on the thickness in the direction of the bend, i.e. the "flat" thickness—since there's no reason to bend that cable in the long axis.